# how to save pdf with original file name (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, controller

How can i upload a file and save the file using using original file name ?
Here my controller code ?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Validate request data
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:50000',
            'category' => 'required',
            'year' => 'required|integer'
        ]);

        $file = $request->file
        $filename = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('regulations', $file);

        Document::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'file' => $filename,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'year' => $request->year
        ]);

        //redirect with success
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Done!');
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839495/save-file-with-original-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save File With Original name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839495/save-file-with-original-name)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```php
$file = $request->file('file');

$file->getClientOriginalName();
```